# In PostgreSQL URL I can't use a password containing special characters

Tags: postgresql, psql, password

I have a postgresql database in Azure

The **passwd** string has special characters like these:

```
)mvd99/iyH_=ag=Por/W}%%aKY^ygt+,sC7%%P?APOU
```

```
psql --dbname=postgresql://db_user@mydemoserver:)mvd99/iyH_=ag=Por/W}%%aKY^ygt+,sC7%%P?APOU@mydemoserver.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/mydb
```

when executing the psql command, it shows me in following error:

> ```
> psql: invalid percent-encoded token: "iyH_=ag=Por/W}%%aKY^ygt+,sC7%%P"
> ```

I already tried putting the passwd string in quotation marks but it does not work

What other options do I have?
I can not change the passwd

I'm interested in using the psql client, because I have to do very large backups

Answer (score 17):

You have to use URI escapes for all problematic characters.

For this user:

```
CREATE ROLE "weird@name" PASSWORD '\/ @&?' LOGIN;
```

You can login like this:

```
psql postgresql://weird%40name:%5C%2F%20%40%26%3F@localhost:5432/test
```

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6) has it:

> Percent-encoding may be used to include symbols with special meaning in any of the URI parts, e.g. replace `=` with `%3D`.

Answer (score 4):

##### Solutions (Linux)

Option A (environment variable): `PGPASSWORD="my{@ugly}:password!#" psql -U admin -d my-db`

Option B (url encode; requires that `jq` be installed): `psql "postgresql://admin:$(printf %s "my{@ugly}:password!#"|jq -sRr @uri)@localhost:5432/my-db"`

##### Solutions (Windows Powershell)

Option A (environment variable): `$env:PGPASSWORD="my{@ugly}:password!#"; psql -U admin -d my-db`

Option B (url encode): `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web; psql "postgresql://admin:$([System.Web.HTTPUtility]::UrlEncode("my{@ugly}:password!#"))@localhost:5432/my-db"`

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a good idea to specify the password on the command line/in the URL anyway. If you use the `.pgpass`[1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/libpq-pgpass.html) file or the `PGPASSFILE` environment variable you get around this.

Having said that, using a Alpha-Numeric (URL safe, like for example Hex) only password is just as safe and much more portable (if it is random and long enough).

Answer (score 1):

## If your password doesn't contain `!`

If your password doesn't include the `!` character, you can URI encode the password using JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent()` or analogous function in other languages.

## If your password contains `!`

If the password contains the `!` character (or sometimes the `*` too), you can use this JavaScript function to escape all characters:

```
    function percentEncodeAllChars(str) {
        var strEncoded = '';
        for(var i = 0, ilen = str.length; i < ilen; i++) {
            var strHex = parseInt(str.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
            strEncoded += '%' + strHex;
        }
        return strEncoded;
    }
```

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it was useful to me; you can *almost* use `jq` to do the same thing (e.g. `echo '"hello world"' | jq '.|@uri'`). That uses `encodeURIComponent()` underneath which unfortunately doesn't encode *all* characters but it works if you're not dealing with `!`

Answer (score 0):

You can encode this kind of urls in browser console with [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI):

For example get pg_dump command:

```
var DB_USER = 'postgres';
var DB_PASSWORD = 'password';
var DB_HOST = 'localhost';
var DB_PORT = '5432';
var DB_NAME = 'postgres';

var pghost = encodeURI(`${DB_USER}:${DB_PASSWORD}@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/${DB_NAME}`);
var pgdump = `pg_dump --dbname=postgresql://${pghost}`;

console.log(pgdump);
```